# Android onResume() not being called when returning to an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, onresume, onpause

onResume runs at startup as per the app lifecycle, but not when the activity is returned to after pausing:

[image]

Where is meant to call onResume at this stage? the onResume being overriden does not run by itself either.

Comment: there is something wrong with your lock, not with android lifecycle. Post everything related with this lock, and we will help you.

Comment: Good spot Paulo & Onik.

I was looking in entirely the wrong place. For some reason there was a while(true) loop around thread.join in renderview.pause. Removing it fixed the issue.

I'm also going to go back to the tutorial I followed months ago and see why it's even there to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onResume was fine.

onPause contained a function with an infinite loop which should have at least contained a break statement.